# Adicionando componente dinamicamente no React

Tags: javascript, react, react-dom

Estou tentando adicionar um componente dinamicamente dentro de outro no React. De forma que eu clique em algum elemento e que no onClick ele adicione este componente junto a div especificada.

Tentei fazer dessa forma: (O objeto é adicionado mas não renderizado)

```
import React from 'react';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
import { css } from 'glamor';
import Sortable from 'react-sortablejs';

/**
 *
 */
function getCSS() {
  return {
    square: css({
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      border: '1px solid #000',
      cursor: 'move',
      display: 'inline-block',
      marginLeft: '10px',
      textAlign: 'center'
    }),
    circle: css({
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      borderRadius: '50%',
      border: '1px solid #000',
      cursor: 'move',
      display: 'inline-block',
      marginLeft: '10px',
      textAlign: 'center'
    })
  }
}

/**
 *
 */
class DragDuplicate extends React.Component {

  /**
   *
   */
  createSquare() {
    console.log(1);
    document.getElementById('container').append(
      <Draggable>
        <div {...css.square}>Drag</div>;
      </Draggable>
    );
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  createCircle() {
    console.log(2);
    document.getElementById('container').append(
      <Draggable>
        <div {...css.circle}>Drag</div>;
      </Draggable>
    );
  }

  render() {
    let css = getCSS();
    return (
      <div>
        <div {...css.square} onClick={this.createSquare.bind(this)}>Drag</div>
        <div {...css.circle} onClick={this.createCircle.bind(this)}>Drag</div>
        <div {...css.square} onClick={this.createSquare.bind(this)}>Drag</div>
        <div {...css.circle} onClick={this.createCircle.bind(this)}>Drag</div>
        <hr />
        <div id="container"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DragDuplicate;
export { DragDuplicate };
```

Qualquer exemplo de alguma for de fazer isto ajudaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para renderizar um componente `react`, intencionalmente não se pode usar APIs imperativas como `element.append`.

O jeito é mudar seu **estado** para refletir o que você quer renderizar usando `.setState({...})` e usar essa informação para renderizar as mudanças no método `render()`. Não sei se funciona com seu uso de `Draggable` etc, mas é a ideia:

```
class DragDuplicate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {circleShown: false, squareShown: false};
  }    

  createSquare() {
    this.setState({
      squareShown: true,
    });
  }

  createCircle() {
    this.setState({
      circleShown: true,
    });
  }

  renderCircle(css) {
    if (!this.state.circleShown) return null;
    return (
      <Draggable>
        <div {...css.circle}>Drag</div>;
      </Draggable>
    );
  }

  renderSquare(css) {
    if (!this.state.squareShown) return null;
    return (
      <Draggable>
        <div {...css.square}>Drag</div>;
      </Draggable>
    );
  }

  render() {
    let css = getCSS();
    return (
      <div>
        <div {...css.square} onClick={this.createSquare.bind(this)}>Drag</div>
        <div {...css.circle} onClick={this.createCircle.bind(this)}>Drag</div>
        <div {...css.square} onClick={this.createSquare.bind(this)}>Drag</div>
        <div {...css.circle} onClick={this.createCircle.bind(this)}>Drag</div>
        <hr />
        <div id="container">
          {this.renderSquare(css)}
          {this.renderCircle(css)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```